# How to use web sockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm trying to make use of Easy Websockets to come up with a chat application.
http://easywebsocket.org/

Here's the code I have right now. As you can see, I'm trying to log the message on the console every time I click on the send button. It works when I open it up on 2 browsers. But it only works for less than 1 minute.

```
<input type="text" id="txt"/>
<input type="button" value="send" id="sends"/>
<div id="messages"></div>

<script src="jquery171.js"></script>
<script src="easywebsockets.js"></script>   
<script>
    var socket = new EasyWebSocket("ws://sample.com/resource");//I do not understand this part
    socket.onopen   = function(){
        socket.send("hello world.")
    }
    socket.onmessage= function(event){
        console.log(event.data)
    }

    $('#sends').click(function(){
        var txt = $('#txt').val()
        socket.send(txt)
    });
</script>
```

I got this error log from firebug:

[image]

I don't really understand what this all means. Is there something I need to setup in order to make this work?

Comment: I'm currently also playing around with [Easy Web Socket](http://easywebsocket.org/) and get the same error, but I did not understand the solution... As they are saying `You want to use websockets ? You want to broadcast messages to all connected clients ? You don't want to worry about browser compatiblity ? You don't want to set up a server ? Here's all the code you need.` So what did you do to solve the problem with **Easy Web Socket** or did you just use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually happens when the client doesn't use the same protocol version as the server. The server should specify what version it uses, socket.io by default goes with RFC6455 but it can be overridden to go with older hybi-0x.

So, check the following:

- client & server implemented protocol versions
- origin (e.g. localhost) is permitted by server
- firewalls, internet security suites, zonealarms, that kind of stuff

Comment: how do I check those?I don't actually know how to use node.js and socket.io

Comment: Depends on a big load of factors, but if you're the one who's hosting the chat server, you can get away with it easier by implementing [Now.JS](http://nowjs.com/) - check out the "10 line chat room" example.

Comment: can this be installed on Windows? I tried npm install now but I got errors, I already tried installing socket.io first and got it installed but still I can't install now.js

Comment: Yes, there's a dependency which needs to be installed manually. Just google the error you'll find the solution within the first results.